# Path with highest sum in a Tree

Tags: java, tree

I have to find maximum sum starting from root node to the leaf node.
I have come up with the following node but it does not give correct output. The tree can have more than 2 child nodes (it is not a binary tree).

```
public static long findBestPath(Path path) {
    long max = 0, sum = 0;
    if (path.getChildren().size() == 0)
        return path.getValue();
    else if (path.getChildren().size() == 1)
        return path.getValue() + findBestPath(path.getChildren().get(0));
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            sum = path.getChildren().get(i).getValue() + findBestPath(path.getChildren().get(i));
            if (sum > max)
                max = sum;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

I used another method to solve my problem. Though it would be good to know correct solution to find path with max sum for a non-binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake should be in this line:

`sum = path.getChildren().get(i).getValue() + findBestPath(path.getChildren().get(i));`

You have to write:

`sum = path.getValue() + findBestPath(path.getChildren().get(i));`

Also you dont need the "else if" in the middle, which is for the case the path has only one children, the "else" works also fine with only one children.

So your code should look like this:

```
public static long findBestPath(Path path) {
    long max = 0, sum = 0;
    if (path.getChildren().size() == 0)
        return path.getValue();
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            sum = path.getValue() + findBestPath(path.getChildren().get(i));
            if (sum > max)
                max = sum;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

I hope it works.

Another Solution, which returns the sum of child(i) + max sum of children of child(i) (If I understood you right), would be:

```
public static long findBestPath(Path path) {
    long max = 0, sum = 0;
    if (path.getChildren().size() == 0)
        return 0;
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            sum = path.getChildren().get(i).getValue() + findBestPath(path.getChildren().get(i));
            if (sum > max)
                max = sum;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

**Both only works, if all values are positive.**

Comment: This does not work, because the sum of child(i) + max sum of children of child(i) should be the values returned.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with "the sum of child(i) + max sum of children of child(i) should be the values returned".

Comment: I hope i understood you right and the other code works for you.

Answer (score -2):

for good explanation you can refer from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-sum-path-in-a-binary-tree/)

Comment: Sorry, cannot upvote. I do not have enough reputation.